# Persisting data for catch-all search

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, persistence

We have a set of catch all search pages we're creating in our ASP.NET application.  We have an initial search page, a SERP, and then a single item details page.  All 3 pages have a search bar with initial criteria, more criteria, and advanced criteria choices.

When we put all of our criteria together, in addition to the main search box we have 20 different criteria parameters (from price, to price, sale item, date created, etc.) and then three collections of parameter IDs.  These collections are from a list of the Manufacturers, Product Lines, and Categories our users can search from.  So we have this fixed set of 20 fields and then 3 collections that could have a manufacturer or two, or could hold a collection of 100 Guids for the lines whose checkboxes they selected and want to search through.

In our old system we had a single form solution and we just posted back and submitted everything to our business object, passing it into a method that returned the results.  In this new form we need to submit the results from page to page and persist this criteria.  We're trying to figure out the best way to persist the data, when I say best I mean most efficient.

Querystring - This isn't going to work with large collections of Guid values for the 3 collections.

Session - We would create a criteria object and store it in the Session.  As they move from page to page we can pull it out.  At our peak we probable have 200-300 people using the server concurrently and the search is our most used form.  I'm worried about performance with all those session variables.

Database - We were thinking of serializing and stashing this criteria object into the database (SQL Server 2k5) and the users would always have a current Search or last Search in the database.  This eliminates some of the web server load from the Session solution but I'm worried this object load, serialization, db round trip, and unload is going to slow the forms down and affect user experience.

I'm looking for advice on which method is going to work most efficiently for us or if there is an accepted best practice or pattern I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 you can use localStorage and sessionStorage, which makes the client keep the information in their browser.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Unfortunately we're saddled with an older platform right now.  We're in asp.net 2.5 and haven't moved to html5 yet.  When we move to 4.5 with better support for html5 we're going to start transitioning.

Comment: Although I'm thinking how nice it would be to create JSON object with the criteria and drop it into local storage nad just pick it up whenever i need to throughout the system.

Comment: I assume you're using Web Forms then?

Comment: I tried this and was able to create a JSON object, fill it with all my criteria, then save it to local storage.  Then on my next page I pulled it out, parsed it, and now I can access it.  Really cool!

However, being a web form application I'm not sure this is my answer because I now need to use that data in my form load to call my search biz object and grab results to bind to my asp.net controls.

Comment: This would be perfect for an MVC app or a html5/jquery app that's calling service.  However, our search engine is not a service engine, it's a business object we call in our asp.net code behind.